# VBA for running javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I am tyring to run JavaScript through VBA in Excel.

```
IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1','Edit$0')"
```

The above code works fine.

I am tyring to click another link through following code which is running a JavaScript. But I am getting an "expected end of statement" error.

```
IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$ctl00", "", true, "", "", false, true))"
```

I have also tried using double quotes `"` like

```
""ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$ctl00""
```

The error has gone but it did not run the script.

Comment: try escaping the quotes with \ e.g. `\"`

Comment: The command that works uses single quotes.  The one that doesn't is using double quotes.  Have you tried single quotes?

Comment: I got it. The existing code is IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$ctl00", "", true, "", "", false, true))" Now the working code is IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(""ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$ctl00"", """", true, """", """, false, true))" -All the string arguments shall be within additional double quotes! Thank You All

Answer (score 1):

I got it.
The existing code is

```
IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1‌​$ctl02$ctl00", "", true, "", "", false, true))"
```

Now the working code is

```
IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(""ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView‌​1$ctl02$ctl00"", """", true, """", """, false, true))"
```

-All the string arguments shall be within additional double quotes! Thank You All